# Iterate Array for Outlook Body

Tags: c#, arrays, outlook

This is the code that I am trying to use. But it isn't actually iterating the array to populate the body as I desire.  What I want to do is use C# to create an outlook email, and populate the receiver, the Message Subject and then generate the Body of the email based of what is contained in the array.  EDIT - I moved the for each loop to attempt to populate the body with each element of the array, but I get a compile error of unable to convert int to string with this code.

```
      public static string GenerateEmail()
{
    try
    {
        for (int q = eName.GetLowerBound(0); q <= eName.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
        {
            return Global.Variables.GlobalVariables.eName[q];
            Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            for (int q = eName.GetLowerBound(0); q <= eName.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
            {
                oMsg.HTMLBody = q;
            }
            oMsg.Subject = "Reports Are Ready";
            Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
            Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("123123123@testemail.com");
            oRecip.Resolve();
            oMsg.Save();
            oRecip = null;
            oRecips = null;
            oMsg = null;
            oApp = null;
        }
    }
    catch 
    {
    }
    return null;
    }           
}
```

Comment: returning in the first statement in loop, empty catch ??? what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Very very often a good old step by step debug session will save you a lot of time and effort...

Comment: Title Edited, you have the C# tag, it doesn't need to be in the title.

Comment: I want to populate the body of a single email with all elements contained in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the very first line in the `for` loop is a return statement, which causes the immediate abbortion of the function.

If you want to populate the message body instead of creating one message per interation, move the declaration of the actual e-mail outside the loop. Then inside the loop append the content to the message:

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
string content = string.Empty;

for (int q = eName.GetLowerBound(0); q <= eName.GetUpperBound(0); q++)
{
    content += "...";
}

oMsg.HTMLBody = content;
// additional settings
```

Comment: Removing the return line (the 1st line of code as you suggested) is now creating a new email for each element of the array, not populating the body of 1 email with every element.